# What's the best method of grabbing info on the most recently posted emoji in a channel using RegEx?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My goal is to be able to grab the most recently posted emoji in a channel and post it's info into a channel without the `<:`, `:`, `>` that are present inside the emoji info.

Here's the code I have so far:

```js
  "yoink": {
    description: "Yoink an emoji",
    usage: "`$yoink`",
    category: "images",
    process: async function(msg, parameters) {
    let a1 = await msg.channel.messages.fetch()
    let a2 = a1.filter(m => msg.content.includes('<'))
    let emoji = a2.first()

    if (a2) {
    msg.channel.send(`${emoji}`)
    }
    }
  },
```

This works but, it simply displays the emoji along with the command syntax, which actually creates an endless loop of commands, lol.

Now, I don't *have* to use RegEx but, I'm trying to learn how it functions.

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: it could be processed like `messages.map(MSG_TO_EMOJI_WITH_PATTERN).filter(IS_EMOJI_MSG)` to get a emoji list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RegEx` to capture the emoji ID, and then fetch that emoji through your `client` to display its information. Here's an example in a code snippet:

```js
// example message
const message = '<:BBwave:562730391362994178> <:MarioWave:725159909758337055> Welcome to the server!'

const [lastEmoji, ...others] = message.match(/<a?:.+:(\d{18})>/).reverse();

console.log(lastEmoji);

// const emote = message.client.emojis.cache.get(emojiID);
// console.log(emote.name, emote.id)
```

---

In my [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function, I used this `RexEx`:

```
/<a?:.+:(\d{18})>/

a? - there is only an 'a' in the emoji if it is animated. question mark means optional
.+ - the emojis name. '.' means any character, and '+' means one or more
\d{18} - the emojis id. '\d' means any standard digit, and {18} means 18 of them in a row
(\d{18}) - by putting the id in parentheses, I can capture it
<::> - every other character is literal
```

Comment: Thank you again for your help and for the little tutorial. I definitely need it!